# Cannot disable logging for VMWare Workstation 11

Tags: vmware-workstation

I can’t prevent VMWare from creating *.log files in virtual machine folder. In previous Workstation 10 I used to change either *.vmx or config.ini file by adding a line:
logging = "FALSE"
But now, after upgrading to version 11, it no longer works and I get error message when trying to start up guest OS. How else can I disable logging?

Comment: Here you go http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1028

Comment: Finally, I figured out what was a problem. Before adding the line logging = "FALSE" to vmx file, the parameter "Log virtual machine progress periodically" in Settings→Options→Advanced must be CHECKED.